# Where can I ask a question about a software project's existing online documentation?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

At work, I use a library called [wxPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WxPython) to write graphical user interfaces.

[Its online documentation](https://docs.wxpython.org/index.html) is very useful in helping me do this, but I'm struggling to understand why the characters `^^` are written in certain places. I don't understand the pattern, so I would like to ask what it means.

On which Stack Exchange site would this be appropriate? I'm aware of Stack Overflow, but I feel unsure if this would be on-topic there, or if there is a site that would be better suited for this question.

Comment: Do you have an example where `^^` appears in the documentation? I tried to search the symbol and it didn't come up with anything

Comment: @GammaGames It's all over this page, for example: https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.CheckBox.html

Comment: Not on Stack Exchange I wouldn't think, maybe https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see why it wouldn't be allowed on Stack Overflow. You're asking for help with what you assume is a part of the library. Whether or not you encounter it in code or in the documentation seems irrelevant to me.

Furthermore, there are [a lot of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=documentation+is%3Aq) involving documentation.

I can't find a relevant thread on SO Meta to dissuade you from it, either.

---

However, in the link you posted in the comment to a few examples, i.e. [this one](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.CheckBox.html), I wonder if the symbols `^^` are part of the documentation or of the formatting of the wiki-like page: on Wikipedia, for example, [references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documentation#References) include single circumflexes. The four instances of the double circumflex only appear at the end of sentences or paragraphs, and might similarly denote a (missing) reference.

Comment: The only place I could find `^^` was their [Doxyfile](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/docs/doxygen/Doxyfile). I didn't see any `|` characters, but I agree it looks like some weird formatting in the templating engine they're using